# Invoke Angular JS code/method from ios code

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, webview, javascriptcore

I know how to access normal Javascript code/methods using JavaScriptCore.h/WebView in iOS. Even am able to access the below mentioned Angular JS code from iOS via WebView.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
             var app = angular.module('app', []);

             app.controller("Ctlr", function($scope,$http){
                $scope.makeReq = function(){
                    $http.get("https://api.github.com/").then(function(response){
                                alert(response.data);
                        });
                    }
            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
        <div ng-controller="Ctlr"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am trying to achieve now is accessing angular.js code without HTML from iOS. In simple words, I will have only a js file which will have angular code and I would like to call from iOS. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

JavascriptCore seems to be the best solution for you. Why don't you use it?